# How much money does Alfred Pennyworth earn?

Tags: dc, batman, gotham, money

Per Batman Wikia

> Alfred starts serving Waynes to honor the dying wish of his father and
>   becomes Bruce's legal guardian following the deaths of his parents
>   (Thomas and Martha left a will).

Is it mentioned anywhere in comics or cinematic universe, how much money Alfred earns while serving Waynes and how does Alfred get his payments when when Bruce is just a kid? Does he own part of Wayne enterprise?

Comment: Please be advised that robbing Batman's buttler would be a terrible life decision on your part.

Comment: In the Nolanverse he... SPOILERS GUYS WATCH OUT... inherits the remnants of Bruce Wayne’s fortune. I kind of wished that in the last scene featuring him he sat down at the cafe, but with the biggest gold chain you ever saw round his neck.

Comment: Paul you are right but excluding what he inherits after Bruce Wayne goes missing

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a figure of $250K per annum bandied about.

Comment: He is worth a penny.

Comment: "Thomas and Martha left a will" No kidding! Thanks Wikia, for telling us that the two most likely candidates for richest parents in the DC Universe left a will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't recall this information being addressed in the comics, much less in the cinematic universe-Nolanverse. According to [this reference](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/2012/07/batman-and-iron-man-infographics/) he earns 80K as a butler and another 150K as a Wayne State manager.

[image]

A basic google ("butler salary" keywords) search showed that

> **A butler usually earns a salary between $50.000 and $150.000 annually, plus benefits**. We realize that the salary indication is very broad but it is what it is. A butler can be a live-in or live-out employee.
>
> <sub>[source: International Butler Academy](http://www.butlerschool.com/en_US/the-extras/interesting-facts/)</sub>

So the information in the picture seems to be "in range".

The payments can be done via a third party, or even Alfred "pays to himself". Basically, if you have kids you may want to make a will in case that (God forbids) something happens to you. There is something called a trust (and probably I may upset lawyers for oversimplifying) but in case that you want to leave everything to your kid, but don't want to leave him a big amount of money when he is not old enough or mature to spend it wisely, you leave it to a trust or third party to administer it. Alfred or some lawyer can be that third party (Alfred could have been named in the will both legal guardian of Bruce **and** manger of the trust for Bruce's inheritance). Since the Wayne trust him enough to make him legal guardian of Bruce they could very well trust him to administer Bruce's wealth and be honest when paying himself his own salary.

Alfred may own part of Wayne enterprises. After all, buying stocks of the company seems like a reasonable way of investing. If the Wayne left him any participation of the company(ies) on their will is unknown on the Nolanverse. Also Alfred could very well be one of those "[various charitable foundations, trusts and so forth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72638/32339)" that Bruce uses in Batman Begins to reclaim control of Wayne Enterprises.

Comment: Link is really interesting and spiderman picking the money is super funny

Comment: This seems good enough but I will wait to see if someone has something from more reliable source.

Comment: As the Nolanverse shows, Bruce Wayne isn't mature enough to handle such a large amount of money, even at thirty.